# Asking for admin permissions in Windows using bash script

Tags: windows, bash, permissions, admin, hosts

I'm trying to alter my `hosts file` in Windows using a **bash script**.

It looks like this:

```bash
echo "<ip_address>  <replacement>" >> C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts
```

It looks like I need admin permissions, how can I get those? I tried this, but it didn't work either.

```bash
cd C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc

chmod +x hosts

echo "<ip_address>  <replacement>" >> C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts
```

Result

```
chmod: changing permissions of 'hosts': Permission denied
bin/exec.sh: line 5: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts: Permission denied
```

Having to accept a pop-up that asks for permissions is acceptable!

Comment: What is `chmod +x` supposed to do here? Why do you want to make the hosts file executable? That doesn't make sense, it's a configuration file, not a script or binary.

Comment: Anyway, I recommend this very useful tool: https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo - Note however that `gsudo echo .. >> ..` won't be enough because the `>> ..` part is done by the shell which is not elevated, but `gsudo bash -c 'echo .. >> ..'` should work.

Comment: @CherryDT I will test it out rightaway!

Comment: Hm I think it has to be `'bash -c ...'` and not `bash -c '...'` actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unfortunately very complicated to achieve this without external tools.

I recommend this very useful tool: https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo - it works like `sudo` but for Windows.

Note however that `gsudo echo .. >> ..` won't be enough because the `>> ..` part is done by the shell which is not elevated and gsudo probably can't run `echo` since that's a builtin, but `gsudo 'bash -c echo .. >> ..'` should work:

```bash
gsudo 'bash -c echo "<ip_address>  <replacement>" >> C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts'
```

Note: If this doesn't work because either your `bash.exe` is not in your Windows `PATH` or because despite this being MINGW bash you also have WSL installed and gsudo would start that instead, then you can always use cmd instead of bash:

```bash
gsudo 'cmd /c echo "<ip_address> <replacement>" >> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts'
```

Comment: What could cause the following error: `<replacement>\ >> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts": -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching \`"'
<replacement>\ >> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts": -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: Not sure - maybe you have WSL installed as well? - you can try going the cmd route instead

Comment: To avoid those extra problems with quotes, backslashes, redirections, etc. you can also put the actual change in a separate script and then run that script with gsudo from the main script.

Comment: I do have WSL installed, however I'm executing this command using Git Bash. Could that be the problem because the cmd version isn't working as well. I'm currently debugging it

Comment: The issue with WSL is that it means that `bash` will resolve to WSL and not Git Bash, unless run from Git Bash. But `gsudo` will start a separate process in another environment to make it admin and just redirect inputs/outputs, so `bash` in gsudo's context would resolve to WSL. But the cmd version should work, what is the issue with it?

Comment: Separating the actual command from the gsudo did the trick. So `gsudo bash script.sh` works for me using bash (+wsl2)